# value from @Input invalid after ngOnInit Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I face with strange problem an `@Input` variable changed after `ngInit` called.

So, I have 3 angular component like this

AcComponent.html

```
<div *ngFor="let d of this.deviceService.ObservableDevice | async;index as idx; trackBy: trackingIdenity">
    <app-ac-controller [device]="d"></app-ac-controller>
</div>
```

AcController.html

```
<div class="col-md-8 position-relative">
     <div class="vertical-line"></div>
     <app-ac-panel [ac]="this.device.ac" [deviceId]="this.device.id"></app-ac-panel>
</div>
```

And `AcPanel.component.ts` as leaf component
the problem happen here

```
export class AcPanelComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public ac: AcModel;
  @Input() public deviceId: number;
  
  constructor(public deviceService: DeviceService, private cdr : ChangeDetectorRef) { 

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('ngOnInit: ' + this.deviceId);
  }

  public powerModeHandler(toMode: string): void {
    console.log(`powerModeHandler for deviceId ${this.deviceId}`);
  }

  public modeHandler(toMode: string): void {
    console.log(`modeHandler for deviceId ${this.deviceId}`);
  }
}
```

When I press button on element `deviceId = 2`

- press button to call powerModeHandler() log print correct **deviceId =
  2**
- press button to call modeHandler() log print **deviceId = 1** ??? (I don't know why)
  I'm sure when `ngInit` it's assign correct `deviceId` on each element

Here log when `ngOnInit` call

```
ngOnInit: 1
ngOnInit: 2
ngOnInit: 3
```

Any one know what reason this case happen and how to fixed this.

Thank you.

**Update.** Added Stackblitz

[stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hdjumu?embed=1&file=src/app/ac-panel/ac-panel.component.ts&theme=dark)

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz showing the issue?

Comment: It is normally that input changes after ngOnInit especially when using observables. To check if the input really changes implement the ``onChanges`` method, it is called before ngOnint but already if something changed after

Comment: @Fussel I added stackblitz in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the radio buttons....

Took me forever to home in on the problem. Your radio buttons have all the same `id` attribute, and your `label` elements get confused!!

This is what you have to do to fix it:

```html
<input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnMode" id="btnCool_{{deviceId}}" autocomplete="off" (change)="this.modeHandler('COOL')">
<label class="btn rounded-0 fw-bold" for="btnCool_{{deviceId}}"
       [ngClass]="{'btn-info': this.ac.mode === 'COOL', 'btn-outline-info': this.ac.mode !== 'COOL'}">
  Cool
</label>
```

To be honest, I'd also change the `name` attribute in the same way...

Comment: Wowww I never know before that  element ID in each component has effect like this. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh btw, your template is full of `this.` you dont need to specify `this.` inside a template, it is implied.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on `modeHandler` in `deviceId = 2 or 3` you see that page scrolls up to `deviceId = 1`. It seems you click on `modeHandler` in `deviceId = 1`!!

So this happen because you are in loop (`*ngFor`) and using same `id` for radio button (and also for label `<label for="btnCool">`).

It is good idea to use dynamic id when you use `*ngFor`. you can use `index` or any `id` you know it is unique. Here you can use `deviceId`

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnMode" id="btnCool{{deviceId}}" autocomplete="off" (click)="this.powerModeHandler('COOL')">
    <label class="btn rounded-0 fw-bold" for="btnCool{{deviceId}}"
           [ngClass]="{'btn-info': this.ac.mode === 'COOL', 'btn-outline-info': this.ac.mode !== 'COOL'}">
        Cool
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnMode" id="btnDry{{deviceId}}" autocomplete="off" (click)="this.modeHandler('DRY')">
    <label class="btn fw-bold rounded-right" for="btnDry{{deviceId}}"
           [ngClass]="{'btn-secondary': this.ac.mode === 'DRY', 'btn-outline-secondary': this.ac.mode !== 'DRY'}">
        Dry
    </label>
</div>
```

[ForkedStackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6k2coc?embed=1&file=src/app/ac-panel/ac-panel.component.ts&theme=dark)

Comment: Thank you for your reply I got my new knowledge about same ID on each component. now I follow you suggest and It's work like my expect Thank you again :)